# My Python 3 causes compile error but there isn't error I think

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to solve 6174 problem.

So I made code like below.

http://cfile9.uf.tistory.com/image/254FDD4955CA9C85082FE2

But it causes error when I input 1112.

http://cfile8.uf.tistory.com/image/2448F44955CA9C860DD8A1

I don't understand why it causes error. I think that is right code.

Is it just python 3 bug or not?

p.s. - Because I can't post images, I leave images' links.

Comment: You shouldn't paste images of code; post the code as text.

Comment: No, it's not a bug in Python. :)

Comment: The chances of it *ever* being a Python bug is so low it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: I'd be happy to help once you put the code and traceback directly in the question :P. Please also include a description of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am sorry that I don't know how to post the code as text. The reason why I linked image is when I type the code, it is broken. So it was difficult to read.

Comment: Select the code, and then hit the {} button to format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, it'd be due to the fact that some of the numbers obtained in that subtraction procedure have fewer than 4 characters. For example, 1001 - 1001 = 0. The string representation of `0` is just `"0"`, and so calling `a[1]`, `a[2]`, or `a[3]` would go out of bounds.

EDIT: Specifically, 2111 - 1112 = 999. As a string this is "999", which only has three characters. Thus calling `a[3]` results in an out-of-bounds error. If you want to fix this, you could do the following.

```
a = input()

for i in range(0,1000):
    digits = len(a)           ##You need to mind how many digits a has
    n = [0, 0, 0, 0]          ##Initialize all the digits of n to 0
    for j in range(0, digits):
        n[j+4-digits] = a[j]  ##Fill up n with an offset if a has fewer than 4 digit
    a = n[0]*1000 + n[1]*100 +n[2]*10 + n[3]
    b = n[3]*1000 + n[2]*100 +n[1]*10 + n[0]
    if b - a == 6174:
        break
    a = str(b-a)

print (i+1)
```

Check for yourself that this works. If `a = "999"`, `n` will be `[0,9,9,9]`, as it should be. Your code as it is currently written will set `n = [9,9,9]`, which will lead to an index error when you call `n[3]`.

After changing the code accordingly, the program yields the correct output (I presume). For `a = "1112"`, the sequence of `a` values over iterations is `999` `8991` `8082` `8532`, and the final value printed is `5`.

Hope that helps!